# Logo is showing on small screen but not on screen size above 720px

Tags: logo

https://utahsportscommittee.com/

You can check the site, it doesn't show logo on bigger screen. when you reduce the size of the logo it displays itself.

Comment: The logo block is being controlled by media query and is set to only display on a smaller screen. Check media query.

Answer (score 1):

In css

https://utahsportscommittee.com/wp-content/themes/Splash/assets/css/skins/skin-custom-sky-blue.css?ver=3.4.2

Line number: 22425

class name: .stm-header-mobile

Remove display: none;

Note: check theme demo which one is use. in demo theme logo will be display or not